# CreateDC function return NULL

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-ce

I have a problem with `CreateDC` function. After calling on `hDC` handle it return `NULL`.

This is snippet of code where are calling function after button pushed down.
`m_pPrint` is a pointer to `Print` class where are defined function connected with Device Context.
It is initialized like

```
m_pPrint = new Print


void MainMenuDlg::OnBnClickedMenuPrint()
{
    
    int nPatientID = m_patientsDlg->m_pCurrSelData->nPatientId;
    int nExamID = m_patientsDlg->m_pCurrSelData->nExamId;
    m_outPrintingManager->PrintEcgSignal(nPatientID, nExamID);
    short* sigPointer = m_outPrintingManager->GetSamplesPointer();

    m_pPrint->PrinterInit();
    m_pPrint->PageSetup();
    m_pPrint->StartPrint();
    m_pPrint->SignalAdjust(80,1000);
    m_pPrint->DrawECG(sigPointer, 12, 9000);
    m_pPrint->EndPrint();

    
}
```

This is header file of `Print` class

```
    class Print
{
protected:

    HWND hwnd;
    CDC hDC;
    int start_x;
    int start_y;
    //LPCWSTR captions[12] = { L" I ", L" II", L"III", L"aVR", L" aVL ", L"aVF", L"V1", L"V2", L"V3", L"V4", L"V5", L"V6" };
    LPCWSTR captions[12];
    int limit_x;
    int limit_y;
    int printmode;
    int width;
    int new_sign_len;
    int channel_nr;
    int startSample;
    int channels[13];
    int mode;
    float sig_speed;
    float amplitude;
    int offset;
    int channel_start;
    int channel_stop;
    int tmp_channel;
    float frequency;
    int space;
    int page;
    BOOL orientation;
public:
    Print();
    ~Print();
    int Print();
    BOOL PrinterInit();
    BOOL PageSetup();
    BOOL StartPrint();
    BOOL DrawGrid(int start_x, int start_y, int limit_x, int limit_y, int width);
    BOOL EndPrint();
    void DrawECG(short * pointer, int channel_nr, int channelLength);
    void SignalAdjust(int start_x, int limit_x);
    void rysujEKG_Vertical(short * pointer, int start_x = 20, int limit = 1100, int offset = 60);
    void rysujEKG_Horizont(short * pointer, int start_x, int limit, int offset);
    void setSpeed(float s);
    void setAmplitude(float a);
    void setPrintMode(int printmod);
    void setChannelStart(int chan_start);
    void setChannelOrder(int * pointer_channel);
    void setChannelStop(int chan_stop);
    void setChannelNr(int chan_nr);
    void setSpace(int sp);
    void setPage(int pg);
    void setSignalLength(int sl);
    void setOrientation(int orient);
    void setStartSample(int startsample);
    float getSpeed();
    float getAmplitude();
    float getFrequency();
    int getChannelNr();
    int getPrintMode();
    int getChannelStart();
    int getChannelStop();
    int getSpace();
    void DrawScaleVertic(int x, int y);
    void DrawExaminationTextBox_Horizont(int start_x, int start_y, int stop_y);

}
```

;

And function `PageSetup` where `CreateDC` is calling.
`hDC` is `CDC` type.
Is initialized like `CDC hDC`

```
BOOL Print::PageSetup()
{

    ZeroMemory(&psd, sizeof(psd));
    psd.lStructSize = sizeof(psd); // psd is member of PAGESETUPDLG structure
    psd.hwndOwner = NULL;
    psd.hDevMode = hMode; // Don't forget to free or store hDevMode.
    psd.hDevNames = hNames; // Don't forget to free or store hDevNames.
    psd.Flags = PSD_INHUNDREDTHSOFMILLIMETERS | PSD_MARGINS | PSD_MINMARGINS;
    psd.rtMargin.top = user_margins.top;
    psd.rtMargin.left = user_margins.left;
    psd.rtMargin.right = user_margins.right;
    psd.rtMargin.bottom = user_margins.bottom;
    psd.rtMinMargin.top = 100;
    psd.rtMinMargin.left = 100;
    psd.rtMinMargin.right = 100;
    psd.rtMinMargin.bottom = 100;
    psd.ptPaperSize.x = papersize.x;
    psd.ptPaperSize.y = papersize.y;
    psd.lpfnPagePaintHook = NULL;
    lf_vertic.lfHeight = 30; // is member of LOGFONT structure
    lf_vertic.lfWidth = 0;
    //lf.lfOrientation = 2700;
    lf_vertic.lfEscapement = 0;
    lf_vertic.lfUnderline = FALSE;
    lf_vertic.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;
    lf_horizont.lfHeight = 30;
    lf_horizont.lfWidth = 0;
    //lf.lfOrientation = 2700;
    lf_horizont.lfEscapement = 2700;
    lf_horizont.lfUnderline = FALSE;
    lf_horizont.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;

    lf_exam_param.lfHeight = 30;
    lf_exam_param.lfWidth = 0;
    lf_exam_param.lfEscapement = 2700;
    lf_exam_param.lfUnderline = FALSE;
    lf_exam_param.lfWeight = FW_NORMAL;

    hFontVertic = CreateFontIndirect(&lf_vertic);
    hFontHorizont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf_horizont);
    hFontExamParam = CreateFontIndirect(&lf_exam_param);
    PRINTDLG pd;
    pd.hwndOwner = NULL;
    pd.rcMargin.top = 3000;


    if (PageSetupDlg(&psd) == TRUE)
    {
        memcpy(&dm, (DEVMODE *)(psd.hDevMode), sizeof(DEVMODE));
        lstrcpy(DriverName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wDriverOffset)));
        lstrcpy(DeviceName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wDeviceOffset)));
        lstrcpy(OutputName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wOutputOffset)));
        lstrcpy(OutputName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wOutputOffset)));
        user_margins.left = psd.rtMargin.left;
        user_margins.right = psd.rtMargin.right;
        user_margins.bottom = psd.rtMargin.bottom;
        user_margins.top = psd.rtMargin.top;
        papersize.x = psd.ptPaperSize.x;
        papersize.y = psd.ptPaperSize.y;
        dm.dmPrintQuality = 300;
        dm.dmPaperSize = DMPAPER_A4;
        hDC.CreateDC(DriverName, DeviceName, OutputName, &dm);
        return TRUE;
}
```

[image: hDC Debugging]

Comment: If CreateDC returns null, call GetLastError to get an idea why it failed.

Comment: The PAGESETUPDLGA member `hDevMode` contains a **handle** to a DEVMODE object. Are you sure you can simply cast it to a `DEVOMOD*`. I would verify that the members of the DEVMODE struct are plausible. Usually the HGLOBAL requires a GlobalLock to get the pointer to the data. -- Since you run it in a debugger it should be sufficient to print the DEMOVE struct to the debugger log.

Comment: @500 [CreateDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdca) (like most of the GDI) predates the introduction of per-thread error reporting. It will **not** set the calling thread's last error on failure.

Comment: @IInspectable: Windows CE SDK documentation suggests it.

Comment: Windows CE is a different OS. It doesn't share its kernel nor windowing code with the NT line of products. Its API is similar to the Windows API, though frequently with different contracts (as in this case). Calling `GetLastError` in response to a failed call to `CreateDC` on Windows will not return a meaningful value.

Answer (score 0):

When I work with the `DEVMODE` structure I do it like this:

```
void CCommunityTalksApp::GetPageSettings(CPrintInfo *pInfo, short &dmPaperSize, short &dmOrientation)
{
    PRINTDLG    pd;
    DEVMODE FAR *pDevMode = nullptr;

    pd.lStructSize = (DWORD)sizeof(PRINTDLG);

    if(pInfo == nullptr)
    {
        if(GetPrinterDeviceDefaults(&pd))
        {
            // protect memory handle with ::GlobalLock and ::GlobalUnlock
            pDevMode=(DEVMODE FAR *)::GlobalLock(m_hDevMode);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // protect memory handle with ::GlobalLock and ::GlobalUnlock
        pDevMode=(DEVMODE FAR *)::GlobalLock(pInfo->m_pPD->m_pd.hDevMode);
    }

    if(pDevMode != nullptr)
    {
        // is it set to landscape
        dmPaperSize = pDevMode->dmPaperSize;
        dmOrientation = pDevMode->dmOrientation;
    }

    if(pInfo == nullptr)
    {
        ::GlobalUnlock(m_hDevMode);
    }
    else
    {
        ::GlobalUnlock(pInfo->m_pPD->m_pd.hDevMode);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I make use of the `::GlobalLock` and `::GlobalUnlock` methods:

- `pDevMode=(DEVMODE FAR *)::GlobalLock(m_hDevMode)`
- `pDevMode=(DEVMODE FAR *)::GlobalLock(pInfo->m_pPD->m_pd.hDevMode)`
- `::GlobalUnlock(m_hDevMode)`
- `::GlobalUnlock(pInfo->m_pPD->m_pd.hDevMode)`